# Callback from slidetoggle function starts wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, accordion

I´ve got a problem with my accordion. The parent element "group" should get the value height from "toggle_container" and it should slide down like "toggle_container".

But in my function, every element "group" gets the value and it doesnt slide down.

### JS Code

```
$('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
                $('.trigger').click( function() {
                    var trig = $(this);

                    if ( trig.hasClass('trigger_active') ) {
                        trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow',function () {
                            $(".group").css({'padding-bottom':($(".toggle_container").height()+'px')});

                            });
                        trig.removeClass('trigger_active');
                    } else {
                        $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow',function () {
                            $(".group").css({'padding-bottom':($(".toggle_container").height()+'px')});

                        });
                        $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
                        trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
                        trig.addClass('trigger_active');

                    };

                return false;
                });
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kfcgg/6/

Comment: your accordion is horizontal, so if you want to use an animation like slideDown use animate function and increase height wherever you want, I am not able to understand what kind of animation you want to provide  you with a solution.

Comment: When i trigger the slide function the "group" element should slide down aswell like the element "toggle_container".

Comment: your group element already has a height you want it to slide Down further more or should it have 0 height in the beginning and then height should increase later on??

In both the cases once the height is increased if i click on next element should the group element collapse and expand again??

Please explain.

Comment: Yes, the "group" element open and close at the same time withe the "toggle_container" element.